# rebind one parameter of std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

In my C++ project I decided to give the new++ features a try. One of those features is the binding of a function with [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) via [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Now I came to a use case, where I have to *rebind* the `std::function`.

Consider the following simplified code:

```
class Test
{
public:
    void first()
    {
        second(bind(&Test::third, this));
    }

    void second(function<void()> fun)
    {
        Test *other = new Test();
        fun->rebindLastParameter(other); // How can I do this?
        fun();
    }

    void third()
    {
        // This is called in context of "other"
    }
}
```

How can I do the `fun->rebindLastParameter(other);` part (replace `this` pointer with `other`)?

**(EDIT) Context:**

In my application there are several classes which inherit from a class called `BaseModel`. Those classes are automatically transpiled from a self made description language. The following class represents a simple "asteroid" which consists of two other "asteroids":

```
#pragma once

#include "BaseModel.h"
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

class Test : public BaseModel
{
public:
  Test(const OBB& start_obb) : BaseModel(start_obb) {}

  void __init() {
    scene();
  }
  void scene() {
      combine(bind(&Test::asteroid, this),bind(&Test::asteroid, this));
  }

  void asteroid() {
      translate(random_float(),random_float(),random_float());
      sphere(7);
      repeat(400,bind(&Test::impact, this));
  }

  void impact() {
      auto p1 = random_surface_point();
      select_sphere(p1,random_float() * 2 + 1,1.0);
      normalize(p1);
      translate_selection(-p1 * random_float() * 0.4);
  }

};
```

The problem lies in the function `BaseModel::combine`, that combines (via constructive solid geometry) two new objects (1st asteroid and  2nd asteroid):

```
void BaseModel::combine(function<void()> left, function<void()> right)
{
    BaseModel *leftModel = (BaseModel*) ::operator new (sizeof(BaseModel));
    BaseModel *rightModel = (BaseModel*) ::operator new (sizeof(BaseModel));
    leftModel->initWithStartOBB(*this->obb);
    rightModel->initWithStartOBB(*this->obb);

    auto newLeft = bind(left, leftModel); // This does not work
    auto newRight = bind(right, rightModel);  // This does not work

    newLeft();
    newRight();

   // ... CSG stuff
}
```

As `leftModel` and `rightModel` have to be new models of the same class, I need to *rebind* the first parameter I previously give in my automatically transpiled class `Test::scene`.

Perhaps I'm on the wrong track. I hope that additional context could explain why I've run into that problem.

Comment: `third()` does not take any parameters, so why do you want to use `bind` here?

Comment: @tobi303 `third()` is a member function and as such the first parameter is always the pointer of the `Test` object it is executed on.

Comment: @Timm: please provide more info as it is not clear what do you want to achieve

Comment: @SimonKraemer yes I know, but then I would probably simply call the methods with differrent objects rather than `bind` the methods to different objects

Comment: @tobi303 Yeah, I don't think the example shows the real problem...

Comment: @MichałWalenciak I want to replace the already bound parameter of the function object. I will edit my question to give more context.

Comment: even ignoring the fact that `third` is a class method, I dont understand why "rebinding" would be necessary. Just create another `function` by binding `third` to some other parameter, you do not have to reuse the old function.

Comment: I hope `BaseModel` has a trivial default constructor and has no virtual functions, otherwise `leftModel->initWithStartOBB(*this->obb);` on uninitialized memory returned by `operator new` is undefined behaviour. You can't call a member function on an object that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::mem_fn` is what you are looking for, as it generates wrapper objects for pointers to members.

```
std::function<void(Test*)> f = std::mem_fn(&Test::third);
f(this);
Test *other = new Test();
f(other);
```

With `std::bind`, use fun with a reference to `Test` object. This way you can call it with a new object

```
void second(std::function<void(const Test&)> fun)
{
    Test *other = new Test();
    fun(*other);
}
```

Or with `this` object

```
fun(*this);
```

Comment: Thanks, I now use `std::mem_fn` and pass `this` per default and `other` in my special use case.

Answer (score 3):

As @tobi303 and others have noted, your function signature for the argument of `second` is too constrained, as it takes a nullary function. There is nothing to rebind - it doesn't take any parameters.

In order to achieve something like it looks like you're trying to do, you need to have the argument of `second` be less constricted. There are several ways of doing so (making it take a `function`, or a pointer to a member function); the following shows it template-parameterized by a function that takes a unary argument:

```
#include <functional>                                                                                                                           


using namespace std;


class Test
{   
public:
    void first()
    {   
        second([](Test *p){p->third();});
    }   

    template<class Fn> 
    void second(Fn fn) 
    {   
        Test *const other = new Test();
        fn(other);
    }   

    void third()
    {   
        // This is called in context of "other"
    }   
};  


int main()
{   
    Test t;
    t.first();
}
```

---

Personal viewpoint (one that earned me several downvotes): I think the use of many libraries and techniques, most cases of `bind` for sure, most cases of `function` - simply precede current lambda functions, and there is less and less of a need for them.

Comment: Totally agree about lambda being more natural than `std::function` in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I do the `fun->rebindLastParameter(other);` part (replace `this` pointer with `other`)?

You can't, in general.

`std::function` relies on [type-erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) which means the original type of  the object that was stored in the `std::function` is not part of the type, and not easily accessible.

If you know for certain that the `fun` definitely stores an object returned by `bind(&Test::third, this)` then there's no need to rebind the argument, just modify `fun` to hold a completely different function object with the right argument, i.e.

```
fun = bind(&Test::third, other);
```

If you know it definitely stores an object returned by `bind( &Test::???, other)` where `&Test::???` is any member function with **exactly** the same signature as `Test::third` then you could do something like this:

```
using binder_type = decltype(bind(&Test::third, this));
if (auto target = fun.target<binder_type>())
{
   // *target is the result of the bind() expression
}
```

But there's still no way to modify the object at `*target` to replace the `Test*` pointer it holds.

If you know the set of functions that could have been used then you could do:

```
using binder_foo_type = decltype(bind(&Test::foo, this));
using binder_bar_type = decltype(bind(&Test::bar, this));
using binder_baz_type = decltype(bind(&Test::baz, this));
if (fun.target<binder_foo_type>())
{
   fun = std::bind(&Test::foo, other);
}
else if (fun.target<binder_bar_type>())
{
   fun = std::bind(&Test::bar, other);
}
else if (fun.target<binder_baz_type>())
{
   fun = std::bind(&Test::baz, other);
}
```

But these are not general purpose solutions and not very maintainable.